# What is the difference between these two Canon kit lenses?

Tags: lens, kit-lens

I want to but a Canon 1100D, but I have no idea between these kits:

Canon 1100D IS
Canon 1100D IS II

The site is in Germany, so I couldn't understand very well, but when I
tried to translate, I didn't see any difference.

Here is the IS:

http://www.fotovideoplus.ch/index.php?dbc=268f1ca2a07f912abb34ec3d856e2aca&page=1753&productNo=106235&pageType=&dbc=268f1ca2a07f912abb34ec3d856e2aca

And here is the IS II:

http://www.fotovideoplus.ch/index.php?dbc=268f1ca2a07f912abb34ec3d856e2aca&page=1753&productNo=106236&pageType=&dbc=268f1ca2a07f912abb34ec3d856e2aca

Thanks

EDIT

I'm sorry, the links was not working, but now they are.

Comment: Your links don't work!

Comment: The links still don't work. I think they're session-specific.

Comment: The links still don't work!

Comment: I can't find it (it's almost 2 years old, i guess they probably don't sell the old kit anymore), but the only difference was the lens: 18-55mm IS X 18-55mm IS II.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one gets you the newer version of the kit lens. Both have the same zoom range, aperture, min focus distance, filter size, etc.

The new version (II) has a improved version of the stabilizer and automatically recognizes motion in the panning direction.

Answer (score 0):

The IS II version has cosmetic changes in order to reduce costs such as a painted, not plastic moulded, lens mount alignment mark.  There are no changes to the optical formula or Image Stabilizer.  See [Canon Rebel T3i / EOS 600D Hands-on Preview at DPreview](http://www.dpreview.com/previews/canoneos600d/).

Comment: See http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/about_canon?pageKeyCode=pressreldetail&docId=0901e0248028433f - Towards the bottom there is a clear paragraph saying the contrary. This answer should be voted down but with a reputation of 1, lets let it pass with a warning ;) I'll leave it up to you to check your sources next time.

Comment: @Itai: I'll make sure that the source is accurate.  I've always considered DPreview as reliable, but in the future, I'll confirm with the primary source where available.